# Conectarme a Oursql de docker, mediante un cliente de mysql

Tags: mysqli, docker

He intentado realizar la conexion desde netbeans, heidi sql, sin resultado.

ya he logrado realizar conexiones mediante dockers con mysql normal, pero la Oursql se ha complicado demasiado.

Esta es la instrucion docker para la instalacion del contenedor
Fuente
https://github.com/Gelembjuk/oursql

docker run --name oursql1 -p 9001:8765 -p 9002:8766  -d -it oursql/oursql-server interactiveautocreate -port 9001

agrego imagenes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿El problema cuál es? No queda claro a qué BD no te puedes conectar. ¿Revisaste que el puerto `9001` está libre (no usado por otro proceso) y que no está siendo bloqueado por el Firewall?